# How many geodatabases may be authorized per ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

I need to create and authorize a new ESRI ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase. Our organization has an existing ArcGIS Server license that has already authorized one ESRI ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase. Will I be able to specify the existing ArcGIS Server authorization file to create another enterprise geodatabase within the same organization and network? I would just try except that someone else administers the ArcGIS Server and we are still in the planning stage.

I understand that we will need ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced (not Basic) to Create an Enterprise geodatabase.

Thank you very much - Tim

Comment: Somone here _may_ know the answer but you might get a faster/more accurate response from http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks. I sent the question to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS for Server, which includes enterprise geodatabases, is typically licensed per CPU core ([more info](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/arcgis-server-10-licensing-by-core)). So if you're licensed to run one enterprise geodatabase on a machine, you're licensed to run as many enterprise geodatabases as you want on that machine, or as many as that machine will actually handle. How many it can handle depends on many factors: the hardware, the data, how well you maintain your database, other software running on the machine, etc. etc. etc.

The point is that yes, you can use the same authorization file to create multiple geodatabases.

You're correct that you need ArcGIS for Desktop Standard or Advanced to run the [Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000162000000).